# How to update maven repository in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, build, m2eclipse

Assuming you're already using the [m2eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/), what can you do when it doesn't update the dependencies to the latest in your repo?

For example, on the command line, you can just add the `-U` flag as in

```
mvn clean install -U
```

…to force the dependencies to be updated. Is there something like this within Eclipse? (It doesn't always seem to pick up the latest updates.)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can **right-click** on your project then **Maven > Update Project...**, then select **Force Update of Snapshots/Releases** checkbox then click OK.

Comment: This isn't completely same as -U: When you have old metadata file that  references to a version that does not exist in repositories, updating snapshots doesn't work. In this situation you have to check what maven binary eclipse is using and run in console `/path/to/bin/mvn clean install -U` to get updated metadata file.

Comment: there no option of `Update Snapshots` in my eclipse indigo , do u have any idea how to do in that

Comment: @Hunt You can select the checkbox "Update Snapshots" in the maven build configuration in eclipse to have the dependencies updated.

Comment: In fact not always work. I have to change the version number to a wrong number and then changet it again to the right version to make it work.

Comment: @Hunt in newer eclipse there is option of "Update Project".

Answer (score 48):

In newer versions of Eclipse that use the M2E plugin it is:

Right-click on your project(s) --> Maven --> Update Project...

In the following dialog is a checkbox for forcing the update ("Force Update of Snapshots/Releases")

Comment: I am using eclipse Kepler. I had to check "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" to fix the problem. Thx!

Answer (score 28):

Right-click on your project and choose `Maven > Update Snapshots`. In addition to that you can set "update Maven projects on startup" in `Window > Preferences > Maven`

> **UPDATE**: In latest versions of Eclipse: `Maven > Update Project`.
>   Make sure "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" is
>   checked.

Answer (score 27):

Sometimes the dependencies don't update even with Maven->Update Project->Force Update option checked using m2eclipse plugin.

In case it doesn't work for anyone else, this method worked for me:

- `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

  This will update your *.classpath* file with the new dependencies while preserving your *.project* settings and other eclipse config files.

If you want to clear your old settings for whatever reason, you can run:

- `mvn eclipse:clean`
- `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

  [mvn eclipse:clean](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/clean-mojo.html) will erase your old settings, then [mvn eclipse:eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) will create new *.project*, *.classpath* and other eclipse config files.

Comment: It worked when I found "Force Update" was not working, thanks!

Comment: Thanks I wanted a way without using m2e and this is it

Comment: Awesome! the :clean fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

If Maven update snapshot doesn't work and if you have Spring Tooling, one interesting way is to remove

- Right-click on your project then Maven > Disable Maven Nature
- Right-click on your project then Spring Tools > Update Maven Dependencies
- After "BUILD SUCCESS", Right-click on your project then Configure > Convert Maven Project

Note: Maven update snapshot sometimes stops working if you use anything else i.e. eclipse:eclipse or Spring Tooling

Comment: I tried the higher rated solutions and none of them worked. This was what worked for me, thanks.