# Spring REST web service appContext failed

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I'm trying to create REST web service using Spring.

I have one controller, one appContext.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="service/{url}......<params>) 
//some method here

//some logic here

}
```

And app context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="spring.rest.controller" />

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

</beans>
```

I'm using Tomcat 7, when trying to start get exception:

```
[13:02] ERROR ContextLoader () - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:468)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 15 more
Jul 23, 2013 1:02:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:468)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 15 more
```

Libs that i used - Spring beans, core, context, web, webmvc, security-core, oxm.
P.S. Never used Spring before, so i have no idea what wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the [Spring expression JAR file](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression/3.2.0.RELEASE).

Since you have already have the Spring core JAR file, you should have the expression JAR file if using a project build manager such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) as `spring-expression` is a dependency of `spring-core`. In this case, the chances are that there was an problem deploying expression JAR file (either it doesn't exist in your local Maven repository or is corrupt). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555845/how-to-update-maven-repository-in-eclipse) how to refresh your local Maven repositories.

If you're not using a build manager such as Maven, then you will need to manually download the JAR file, matching the version with your existing Spring JAR files.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) with Spring if your main interest is creating RESTful services. I recently wrote this [article](http://qmino.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/rest-j2ee-soa/) with a working codebase on how to setup RESTEasy with Spring.