# What is the following error while creating maven project?

Tags: java, maven

Project configuration is not up-to-date what is Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml. Select: Maven->Update Project... from the project context menu or use Quick Fix.

Comment: Exactly like it says: your project is not in sync with your pom.xml.  Have you tried doing like the message says and updated your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update maven repository in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555845/how-to-update-maven-repository-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

goto Project>clean(to clean project) and goto Maven->Update Project after updating project rebuild the project.