# package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist even though it's defined in POM

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-web

So I have this code

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
```

And I already have the following in my POM file

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Yet when I built it ends up complaining package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist

Why? I already added spring web as a dependency. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you updated maven ? try `mvn install`

Answer (score 44):

I had a similar issue, I fixed it by going into my pom.xml file and changing the artifactID for the spring boot dependency from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Edit to show explanation:

I was following a tutorial that had me using the wrong dependency. If I remember correctly, the spring-boot-starter-web dependency contains everything spring-boot-starter has, plus what you need to make a basic web app. So my app was looking for some web dependencies that I'm assuming spring-boot-starter does not contain.

Comment: Why does this work? And how did you find this fix? I find this to be very obscure and strange. Especially because I just downloaded the starter project Spring provides...

Comment: In my particular case, I was following a tutorial that had me using the wrong dependency. If I remember correctly, the spring-boot-starter-web dependency contains everything spring-boot-starter has, plus what you need to make a basic web app. So my app was looking for some web dependencies that I'm assuming spring-boot-starter does not contain.

Comment: Indeed! I finally stumbled upon this and -- thanks for that, Cory. I was following the tutorial from spring.io and -- typical of Java tutorials, it is out of date and has not been updated to reflect the apparent new packaging. Maven and spring are supposed to make things easier, but -- I have yet to see that.

Comment: I used the generated code from spring official website and got this error...

Answer (score 8):

Run the following command

```
mvn clean install
```

If you are using IDE like intelliJ idea or Eclipse make sure to re
    import the project.
Here is an answer how to refresh maven dependencies in eclipse

[How to update maven repository in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555845/how-to-update-maven-repository-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

For me, removing the `spring-web` dependency worked. To do this, remove the following from your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean install doesn't fixed issue for me. I clicked in Maven (right tab in Intelij) and then refresh button. Maven downloaded everything and it works now

Comment: Clean the refresh button to reload maven project works for me. Directly click the `pom.xml` and select `reload from disk` seems not to reload the mvn project but to reload the single file.

Answer (score 0):

Trying:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.pxample</groupId>
    <artifactId>pemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.36-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And view the samples below:

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/blob/main/initial/pom.xml

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-multi-module/blob/main/complete/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

i changed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```