# resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of mymaven has elapsed or updates are forced

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project com.my.cms: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.my.cms.jar:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies for [com.my.common.jar:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (compile), 
commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4 (compile)]: 

Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.my.common.jar:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
Failure to find com.my.parent:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://10.168.0.1/nexus/content/groups/public 
  was cached in the local repository,  
  resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of mymaven has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

All the local libraries have jar, but the eclipse plug-in for Maven has been downloaded from the server and reported a timeout error.

Comment: I think that you need to do more than just repeat the error message as a StackOverflow question. Where is the problem occurring, in which environment, on what sort of computer, compiler, processor? And the question should indicate something about what it is related to.

Comment: Please refer to this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555845/how-to-update-maven-repository-in-eclipse

Answer (score 3):

You should at least to a mvn -U to force the update of dependencies, including snapshots.

Actually, read "[How to update maven repository in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28752527/6309)"

```
Maven->Update Project->Force Update
```

Comment: Run in Windows eclipse, JDK7, i5

Comment: My answer would still apply to this environment

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: When I execute maven install, the above exception occurs