# Getting error in pom.xml file which i downloaded from http://start.spring.io

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

**TYPE OF FILE I DOWNLOADED**

Group : com.example
Artifact : easy-notes
Name : easy-notes
Description : Rest API for a Simple Note Taking Application
Package Name : com.example.easynotes
Packaging : jar (This is the default value)
Java Version : 1.8 (Default)
Dependencies : Web, JPA, MySQL, DevTools

**POM FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>easy-Notes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>easy-Notes</name>
    <description>Rest API for a Simple Note Taking Application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**ERROR MSG**

> Failure to transfer org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
>   org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:240)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:208)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:563)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:481)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
>       at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:338)
>       at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:202)
>       at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:212)
>       at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:185)
>       at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:530)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob$1$1.call(ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.java:89)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob$1$1.call(ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1351)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob$1.call(ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.java:87)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob$1.call(ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1355)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.run(ProjectRegistryRefreshJob.java:81)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)

Comment: Delete the content of `$HOME/.m2/repository` and retry on plain command line...BTW: Do you have a proxy/firewall there?

Comment: From stacktrace I presume this is in eclipse so see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46313403/9705485

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When maven says "resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MyRepo has elapsed", where is that interval specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of)