# Cannot find/resolve artifact: Maven error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I just have pulled new projectand when I run mvn clean install I got this error(on other computers build is success):

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:unpack (unpack-swagger-ui) on project kapua-rest-api-web: Unable to find/resolve artifact.: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.kapua.external:swagger-ui:jar:2.1.4-CQ-10792 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Just to say that I know that this question was asked but none of that answers did not help me, so please do not put this as duplicate.Could someone helps me to fin out why I have this Maven error and how to solve it?

Comment: maven build unable to find above-mentioned dependency plugin in your repository, It may be due your version mismatch or dependency not present into your repository so check the version of the dependency and then update your maven global repository

Comment: Are you using on premise repository manager (like Nexus)?

Comment: @KalaiselvanA Sorry,m I am kind of new in Maven, how to update my global repo?

Comment: @rkosegi no, I dont use repository manager...

Comment: @Atenica are you using any IDE?

Comment: @KalaiselvanA I am using eclipse, but all Maven stuff I am doing with terminal...

Comment: @Atenica  it will be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555845/how-to-update-maven-repository-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [issue on github](https://github.com/eclipse/kapua/issues/598) correct way to build kapua is

```
mvn clean install -f external/pom.xml
mvn clean install
```

I expect first invocation to produce missing artifacts into local M2 repo and second invcation to perform actual build.