# Getting NoClassDefFoundError -> com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Psapi with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, jna, oshi

My program relies on the following code to get available system memory:

```
import oshi.SystemInfo;
import oshi.hardware.HardwareAbstractionLayer;


SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();
HardwareAbstractionLayer hal = si.getHardware();

// Next line throws exception: NoClassDefFoundError -> com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Psapi
long availableBytes = hal.getMemory().getAvailable();
double availableMegabytes = ((double) availableBytes) / 1048576;
double availableGigabytes = ((double) availableMegabytes)/1024;
```

**Update:** After deleting every occurrence of `oshi-core` from every project in `Workspace` (to remove possibility of transient conflict dependency - only `4.2.1` is left). Now the error I get is -> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/win32/VersionHelpers`

In `pom.xml` I've added `oshi-core` dependency - I've tried almost every version starting from version `3.4.0` to latest version `4.2.1` and they all result in the same error.

I realize `oshi-core` relies on `jna` and `jna-platform`. In `Dependency Hierarchy` I see both have resolved (compiled) to version `5.5.0`.

What is causing this error and how can it be solved?

Thanks!

P.S

I've seen some other threads with similar error but could not find any thread with this exact problem (missing `com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Psapi`)

Comment: You're not running on Linux, right? Because a Linux JVM is unlikely to have a `win32` class.

Comment: Correct, I'm running on Windows Server. I deleted every occurrence of `oshi-core` from every project in Workspace (only `4.2.1` is left). Now the error I get is: `NoClassDefFoundError: oshi/SystemInfo` ..

Comment: Does that surprise you? That when your code uses `oshi` (perhaps indirectly through some other library), but you don't include it, the code fails with that error?

Comment: Both of those errors are now gone but I get a new error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/platform/win32/VersionHelpers`. It seems that when I take care of one error another one pops up in its place.

Comment: I do know that this project has another project in its build path which requires `jna and jna-platform version 4.1.0` however I do not believe this is leading to the above error because "Resolved Dependencies" section in Eclipse shows current project has the recent version `5.5.0`

Comment: Please post your `pom.xml` file so we can see your dependencies.  Have you added anything to the classpath that wasn't put there by Maven?

Answer (score 2):

While you've pointed out in your comments that you think the latest version of JNA is being resolved, the errors indicate that your project does not have the most recent version of `jna-platform` (or possibly it has multiple versions linked on the classpath).  This is nearly always the case for `NoClassDefFoundError` and while you're troubleshooting in the right direction, evidence indicates there's an old `jna-platform` version in your project somewhere.

The [`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.VersionHelpers`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform/5.5.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/VersionHelpers.html) class is in `jna-platform` version 5.3.0 and newer.  The `GetPerformanceInfo()` method required for the method call giving you the error is in the [`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Psapi`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform/5.5.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Psapi.html#GetPerformanceInfo-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Psapi.PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION-int-) class is in `jna-platform` version 4.3.0 and newer.  If your classloader can't find these classes, then you don't have the correct jars linked to your project -- or you have incorrect jars linked alongside the correct ones.

[Maven resolves dependencies by level](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)... first it does all the dependencies you list in your POM (in order), then the transitive dependencies of those projects (in order) and so on.  Ensuring the most recent version of JNA is used can be enforced by either (or both) of:

- Specify `oshi-core` dependency earlier in your list of dependencies
  in your POM, specifically, before any project that depends on an
  earlier version of JNA.
- Explicitly specify the `jna` and
  `jna-platform` versions (5.5.0) in your top-level POM.

Also, in Eclipse, be sure to go through the menus to [Update Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555845/how-to-update-maven-repository-in-eclipse/24509023) to ensure your dependencies are in sync after changes in the POM.

It's possible that your local repository is not downloading the updated jar, in which case you can purge it (or just delete any JNA artifacts, or everything, from `C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository` and let it rebuild.)

Also check the classpath in Eclipse. If you have manually added dependencies (e.g., to JNA) before setting up your POM to get them from Maven, you could be using those.

If the above hints do not resolve your problem, please post the contents of the dependencies section your `pom.xml` file so we can provide additional advice.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `oshi-core` relies on internal undocumented features of the Sun / Oracle JVM, and you're running on a different and/or newer JVM that doesn't have that *undocumented* feature anymore. That's the risk of using undocumented features.

Get a newer/other version of `oshi-core` that supports the version of the JVM you're using, or switch to use a JVM that `oshi-core` supports.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Oracle JVM and the "features" are well documented in the `jna-platform` javadocs.  The `com.sun` package name is a relic of the origins of the JNA project and have nothing to do with Oracle, and the project is tested against OpenJDK.