# Configure build path problem in eclipse - java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, buildpath, elasticsearch-7

I upgraded the elastic search from version 5.5 to 7.7, everything is working as expected. 
But when I try to get the Total hits, I get the following error

```
searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits()
```

**The type org.apache.lucene.search.TotalHits cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files**

We are not using the lucene library but still, it says it refers to the lucene, 
Any help is appreciated to fix this.

[image]

Maven pom.xml :

I have only these two Jars,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Could you please update the question with your maven/gradle config, looks like lucene library is missing.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal Updated the pom.xml but previously may be the jars on lucene could have been there, which I removed now

Comment: You can either go with the below answer if you have not removed the lucene jars or use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556197/3838328) so that maven re-downloads the required dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-transport-usage-maven-lucene.html), you probably need to add the below dependency:

```
<repository>
    <id>elastic-lucene-snapshots</id>
    <name>Elastic Lucene Snapshots</name>
    <url>https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.elasticsearch.org/lucenesnapshots/00142c9</url>
    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
```

Also as per [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_log4j_2_logger.html), you may also need to add Log4j dependency as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

That should do the trick.

Alternatively you can also add the below lucene dependency with the exact version you can see if you just do `http://<hostname>:9200`, however I suggest the above approach and go as per their documentation.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Opster ED Ninja Kamal

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431157/reindex-api-vs-using-logstash-for-reindexing-from-elastic-search-5-5-remote-to

Comment: Sure, will review and update. Please give me sometime!!

Comment: Could you please help me on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62463191/create-index-request-mapping-is-failing-in-elastic-search