# Reindex API vs using logstash for reindexing from elastic search 5.5 (remote) to elastic search 7.7 (local)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-7

I am looking for migrating the data from elastic search version 5.5 to 7.7, 
I found the following two ways,

1) Re_Index API using Java API : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-reindex.html#java-rest-high-document-reindex

which looks easy (as it involves java code) and able to see all the possible cases for moving all the documents from version 5.5 to 7.7

2) Re_Index API using Curl : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade-remote.html

3) Using logstash : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-reindex-using-logstash/79143

Which is the most proper way to do this? Any advantages or disadvantages in the above?

Comment: There's a fourth way using elasticdump: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34922623/4604579

Comment: @Val How to do the index name change / data structure change ?

Comment: Your question didn't state this :-) Please reformulate your exact needs.